# Liquid Markup space following optional value

Tags: liquid, dotliquid

Is there a standard approach in Liquid Markup to the situation where you want to output a space following a value, but only if that value is present?

For example, let's say I have four values: prefix, first, middle, last. Everyone has first and last, but only some folks have prefix and/or middle.

If I just do `{{prefix}} {{first}} {{middle}} {{last}}`, then if there is no prefix or there is no middle name, I'll end up with extra spaces.

```
Mr. John Mortimer Smith <-- looks fine  
 Mary  Jones <-- looks weird, extra space at beginning and in middle
```

Naturally, I can do

```
{% if prefix != "" %}{{prefix}} {% endif %}{{first}} {% if middle != "" %}{{middle}} {% endif %}{{last}}
```

And that should work but seems messy. Is there a better way?

Thanks!

I was asked for an example. If I go to http://dotliquidmarkup.org/try-online
and enter

```
{% assign first = "Mary" %} {% assign last = "Smith" %}
{{ prefix }} {{first}} {{middle}} {{last}}
```

Then I get

```
 Mary  Smith
```

(with a space before Mary and two spaces after Mary, since prefix and middle are null)

but I want to get

```
Mary Smith
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Any repository url ?

Comment: Edited to add a detailed example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dotliquidmarkup.org/try-online is presenting liquid parsing results in a `<pre>` tag that preserve whitespaces.
That will not be the case in a standard html page where multiple spaces are presented a single one except in `pre` and `code` tags.

If you really want to get rid of multiple spaces, you can use `normalize_whitespace` filter.

#### whitespaces.md

```
---
title: Whitespaces
names:
  -
   prefix: m
   first: first
   middle: middle
   last: last
  -
   prefix: m
   first:
   middle: middle
   last: last
  -
   prefix:
   first: first
   middle:
   last: last
---
{% for p in page.names %}
{% capture fullName %}
  {{ p.prefix }} {{ p.first }}
  {{ p.middle }} {{ p.last }}
{% endcapture %}
<pre>|{{ fullName }}|</pre>
<pre>|{{ fullName | normalize_whitespace }}|</pre>
{% endfor %}
```

No more double spaces or any unnecessary whitespace.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful, but the HTML multiple space handling doesn't help me with the extra space before the first name. I could combine them and then use trim, though.

Comment: This works well here. I've edited my answer with a working example.